# Is there a tighter bound on $\prod_{i=1}^I x_i$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, approximation

If $x_i\in[0,1]$ for all $i=1,2,\cdots,I$, then we have a simple bound on $\prod_{i=1}^Ix_i$, i.e.,
$$\prod_{i=1}^I x_i \le \sum_{i=1}^I x_i.$$

I wonder if there is a tighter bound than the one above?

Comment: It might be helpful to include the constraints you have in mind. E.g., the family $(1+\epsilon)\prod_{i=1}^Ix_i$ provides progressively tighter bounds (optimally tight when $\epsilon=0$), but that observation doesn't provide a satisfactory or meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tightest you can get bounding by one element is $\bar{x} = \min\{x_i : i \in \{1, \ldots, I\}\}$, since
a multiplication by a number less than 1 will lower the product. Hence,
$$\prod_{i=1}^I x_i \leq \bar{x} $$
But of course, you can always bound multiplying by one element less
$$\prod_{i=1}^I x_i \leq \prod_{i=2}^I x_i \leq \cdots$$

Comment: Can't you get a tighter bound by multiplying the two (or three, four, ..., $I-1$) smallest elements?

Comment: @HansMusgrave yes, of course. I edited the post

Answer (score 1):

The Arithmetic Mean Geometric Mean (AM-GM) inequality says that $$\dfrac{1}{I}\sum_{i = 1}^{I}x_i \ge \left(\prod_{i = 1}^{I}x_i\right)^{1/I},$$ and thus, we get the bound $$\prod_{i = 1}^{I}x_i \le \left(\dfrac{1}{I}\sum_{i = 1}^{I}x_i\right)^I.$$

We can check that this bound less than or equal to $\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{I}x_i$ for all $x_i \in [0,1]$.